# Power automate flow applied on current excel file

Tags: excel, power-automate

I use a program that generates Excel reports via a report generator.
I want to insert a button in the report template that triggers a Power Automate flow, transferring some of the report date to Dataverse. The problem is that the Excel file name is different for each Excel report. Is there a way to apply the triggered Power Automate flow on the current Excel file instead of specifying one single file upfront in Power Automate?

Comment: How is the button implemented? VBA, Office Scripts, Office JS?